# How could I run Headless Chromium (Puppeteer) multi threaded?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, phantomjs, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I tried to run it multi threaded with 4 pages open instead of only one, hoping for it to run each process 100% the speed of a thread.

I monitored with `top` and saw that the chrome threads were not at all working at their best, although it previously was at 100% when launched single threaded (with a single page).

I ran benchmarks to see which version would finish first, and it appeared that the single threaded version is even faster.

Did I miss anything?
If it isn't much supported, which of the tools enables for the fastest performances?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `cluster` if you wanna do that manually, or use PM2's cluster mode if you wanna do that automatically.

Node JS's `cluster`:
https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

PM2's with cluster mode:
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/

Comment: This is not exactly the same thing. There should be a way to simply make chromium use a separate core per tab, similar to what chrome does.